# Excel VBA giving a Run-time error when putting an extra "{" in a string? Error code -2147467260(80004004)

Tags: excel, vba, jira, jira-rest-api

The { after fields: causes excel to crash on the .Send(Errordata) line.

```
Sub CurlyError()
    Const URL = "https://jira.example.com/rest/api/latest/issue/issue-1111"
    Const vbDoubleQuote As String = """"
    Dim JiraService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, ResponseTxt As String, sEncbase64Auth As String
    Dim data As String
       
    ' credentials
    sEncbase64Auth = EncodeBase64("USERNAME:PASSWORD")
   
    NoErrorData = "{" & vbDoubleQuote & "fields" & vbDoubleQuote & ":" & vbDoubleQuote & "customfield_555" & vbDoubleQuote & ":" & vbDoubleQuote & "2025-12-11" & vbDoubleQuote & "}}}"
    ErrorData = "{" & vbDoubleQuote & "fields" & vbDoubleQuote & ":{ " & vbDoubleQuote & "customfield_555" & vbDoubleQuote & ":" & vbDoubleQuote & "2025-12-11" & vbDoubleQuote & "}}"
    Debug.Print (ErrorData)
    With JiraService
        .Open "PUT", URL, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck"
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & sEncbase64Auth
        .Send (ErrorData)
        Debug.Print .ResponseText
    End With
End Sub
```

I can always print the data line:

```
NoErrorData  {"fields": "customfield_13000":"2025-12-11"}}
ErrorData {"fields":{ "customfield_13000":"2025-12-11"}}
```

With the NoErrorData line, it is Jira that responds with a java error

```
com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueUpdateBean[\"fields\"])
```

The ErrorData line crashes VBA before the information is sent to Jira.
Below is the function needed to have the above code run.

```
Public Function EncodeBase64(text As String) As String
    Dim arrData() As Byte
    arrData = StrConv(text, vbFromUnicode)
 
    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
 
    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
 
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    EncodeBase64 = objNode.text
 
    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: You need only 2 pairs of brackets. Try `data = Replace("{'fields':{'customfield_555':'2025-12-11'}}", "'", vbDoubleQuote)`

Comment: @CDP1802 Without the intial { Jira will not update the field. The Replace is nice, but does not work for me as the date is a variable not a string value like in the example I provided.

Comment: I don't understand, I have an initial `{`. To be a valid JSON string the brackets need to be balanced with same number of opening `{` as closing `}`. Creating a string shouldn't crash excel regardless of the number of {} brackets. The ErrorData line does not crash Excel for me.

Comment: @CDP1802 thanks, I fixed the brackets in the question. Just to confirm you are able to send the request to Jira without Excel crashing? Are you referencing Microsoft XML, v6.0 Reference or another library?